# Abstract methods do not specify a body

Tags: java

I am getting an error in the Code: Abstract methods do not specify a body

```
public abstract class fruit{
private int myNum;
public fruit (int count){
myNum = count;

public abstract void eat(int num);

public abstract int getAmount();

public abstract int getType()
}
return myNum;
```

Please help me with this coding

```
public class Bananna (int myNum, int count)
  super (myNum, count);
}
public int getType()
{
return get myNum();
}
public return getmyNum();
}
}
```

Comment: add your exception to the question

Comment: Your code does not compile at all. The parentheses are completely messed up.

Comment: Take a look where blocks marked by `{  }` begin an end. Those should match the logical blocks of your code. I suggest (since that code is relatively small) removing it all and start from scratch: first define a class that will compile properly, then add some variables, methods, etc.

Comment: Also, if you format your code so that internal `{ }` block are indented, you would easily see the problem yourself.

Comment: `Bananna` is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Wew there are a lot of wrongs in your code which leads to thinking that you do not understand what you are writing at all.

- class names should be UpperCamelCase by convention (fruit -> Fruit)
- constructor is missing a closing bracket
- getType() is missing a semicolon
- the closing bracket after getType() is not valid
- 'return myNum;' is not valid outside a method, however in an abstract class it is also invalid inside a method as abstract classes do not have method bodies
- 'public return' is not valid
- 'return get myNum;' is not valid
- 'public class Bananna()' is not a valid constructor
- a lot of brackets are just plain wrong

Also, answering your question:
The compiler told you: abstract classes do not have method bodies (unless declared default) which means:

Abstract class method:

```
public void myAbstractMethod();
```

Class method:

```
public void myImplementation() {
    //my code
}
```